# Why is my getString() method always returning null?

Tags: java, string, null, return-value

I have a problem with a file lookup function that I made yesterday, The method used to return a File, But it was always returning null so I changed it to return file path, It is still returning null EVEN when it's not, Here's the code and the output:

```
public static String lookupFile(File file, String name) {
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    if(list != null) {
        for (File fil : list) {
            String n = fil.getName().replace(name, "");
            if (n.length() != 0) {
                if(fil.isDirectory())
                    lookupFile(fil , name);
            } else if (n.length() == 0) {
                String g = fil.toPath().toString();
                System.out.println(fil.getName());
                System.out.println(g);
                return g;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The way i'm using it is like so:

```
String n = Sys.lookupFile(new File(Sys.getAppData() + "g/"), "ggf.rtf");
        System.out.println(n);
```

The output is this:

```
ggf.rtf
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\g\h - Copy (5) - Copy\h - Copy (5)\ggf.rtf
null
```

Why is it turning to null after it's been returned ? Before returning the string, It prints it out, And we can see that it's not null so what's wrong ?

Comment: Post the full class to be more clear.

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger? Can you put in a breakpoint and see where exactly things go wrong and why your method returns null? is your `list` null, i.e. does file.listFiles() return null? These kinds of questions are rather pointless if I'm perfectly frank. They won't teach you anything and no one will be able to help you. You will need to put in breakpoints, see what exactly is happening and then decide where things are going wrong and how to fix them.

Comment: @kha The list is not null, ass you can see, Before it returns "g" it prints it out, And you can see that in the output, It's not null, But when I print the value returned by the function, It's null.

Comment: @StephenC That's the only code I have..

Comment: @ABOODYFJ It may be returning null because you are using recursion and the exact file name is returned somewhere in nested calls and as you are not storing result you have lost the value. When you are making a recursive call store the returned value in a variable and then in the last statement when you are returning null return that variable. Please see my answer for reference.

Comment: Best way is to debug lookupFile(). You will exactly come to know where does it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a new function and a static variable, Like so:

```
private static String gg = null;

public static File lookup(File file, String name) {
    gg = null;
    return new File(lookupFile(file, name));
}

private static String lookupFile(File file, String name) {
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    if(list != null) {
        for (File fil : list) {
            String n = fil.getName().replace(name, "");
            if (n.length() != 0) {
                if(fil.isDirectory())
                    lookupFile(fil , name);
            } else if (n.length() == 0) {
                String g = fil.toPath().toString();
                System.out.println(fil.getName());
                System.out.println(g);
                gg = g;
                return gg;
            }
        }
    }
    return gg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `null` you are getting in the console is returned as result from `lookupFile()` (the code eventually gets to the final `return null` statement). Debug the method and see why that happens, go through your if/else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public static String lookupFile(File file, String name) {
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    String returnValue = null;
    if(list != null) {
        for (File fil : list) {
            String n = fil.getName().replace(name, "");
            if (n.length() != 0) {
                if(fil.isDirectory())
                    returnValue = lookupFile(fil , name);
            } else if (n.length() == 0) {
                String g = fil.toPath().toString();
                System.out.println(fil.getName());
                System.out.println(g);
                return g;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```